# PHP How to Replace string with empty space?

Tags: php, str-replace

Input:

> GUJARAT (24)

Expected Output:

> 24

String Format:

> State Name (State Code)

How can I remove State Code with parentheses?

Comment: This question is very ambiguous in its expectations -- making it Unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [php explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$state = "GUJARAT (24)";
$output = explode( "(", $state );
echo trim( $output[0] ); // GUJARAT
```

Comment: Oh Sorry, my expected output is state code, not a state name. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the stateCode length, and it is fixed

```
$state = "GUJARAT (24)";
$state = substr($state, strpos($state, "(") + 1, 2);
// get string upto "(", and remove right white space    
echo $state;
```

You can check more about [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) in php manual.

If stateCode length is not fixed, you can use regular expression:-

```
  $state = 'GUJARAT (124)';
  preg_match('/(\d+)/', $state, $res);
  $stateCode = $res[0]; 
  var_dump($stateCode);
```

Comment: Oh Sorry, my expected output is state code, not a state name. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "GUJARAT (24)";
echo '<br />1.';
print_r(sscanf($str, "%s (%d)"));
echo '<br />2.';
print_r(preg_split('/[\(]+/', rtrim($str, ')')));
echo '<br />3.';
echo substr($str, strpos($str, '(')+1, strpos($str, ')')-strpos($str, '(')-1);
echo '<br />4.';
echo strrev(strstr(strrev(strstr($str, ')', true)), '(', true));
echo '<br />5.';
echo preg_replace('/(\w+)\s+\((\d+)\)/', "$2", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$fullstring = 'this is my [tag]dog[/tag]';
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, '[tag]', '[/tag]');

echo $parsed; // (result = dog)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the function preg_match

```
$state = 'GUJARAT (24)'
$result = [];
preg_match('/[\(][\d]+[\)]/', $state, $result);
$stateCode = $result[0] // (24)
$stateCode = substr($stateCode, 1, strlen($stateCode) - 2); // will output 24
```

Comment: Oh Sorry, my expected output is state code, not a state name. Please help me.

Comment: I do not recommend that anyone copy this regex. Even if the OP wanted the state id as the result, there is much to correct in the pattern.  You shouldn't ever need to call `substr()` or `strlen()` if you use a capture group.